# Load large data set in sencha store

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm trying to load a store with a rather large data set (600 mb), but the app just freezes. Is  there a limitation for how large the data sets can be in sencha? or should I try a different approach? My stores proxy is simply:

```
proxy: {  
type: 'ajax',
url:'data/listjson.json',  
 reader: {
type: 'json',
rootProperty: 'entries',

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think you're pushing limits. There is really no need for such huge data set to be loaded simultaneously. Can you provide more detail on what exactly you're trying to do - and may be we can help you re-design your application.

Comment: Sure, I'm trying build a synonyms app. The long list of words are the list with words that have synonyms. When the user clicks an item, I get the word and send the word to a webserver with jsonp, and the server then returns the synonyms available for that word in json format. I tried to load the list with words from the the server first, but this seemed to freeze the app also. Or should that approach work? Maybe I made some other mistake when I tried that? Thank's for helping out!

Comment: I would keep that data on the server and retrieve only words which are necessary. If you want to show whole list to user (does't make much sense btw to scroll through 1000s of items) - show only first few (couple dozens) and implement infinite scrolling - i.e. load more words when user scrolls to the down.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, but I did not know if this was possible. Ok, so I show some words, say a dozen, and then I bind a keyup event to the searchfield sending the following, for example, 'mywebserver' + 'enteredwords' to the server and return the word if it exists, and then send another request when the user taps that word fetching the synonyms tied to that word. Is it something like that you mean?